Shopware 6.6 I am getting a CHECKOUT__PAYMENT_TOKEN_INVALIDATED in a custom payment plugin
I am developing a custom payment plugin for my online store and I am getting some issues on making it work with the payment provider from my country:

The return url generated from Shopware is too long to be processed by the payment provider (Max 255 chars). I fixed it by creating a fake return url and saved real return url in database (please let me know if that's the best approach or not).
I test the payment method to approve a transaction and it works well.
When I test the payment rejecting the transaction, it shows a page saying there was a problem which is ok but when I try to complete/repay again with the same payment method I get a CHECKOUT__PAYMENT_TOKEN_INVALIDATED exception.

Pay Method:
public function pay(AsyncPaymentTransactionStruct $transaction, RequestDataBag $dataBag, SalesChannelContext $salesChannelContext): RedirectResponse
    {

        $context = $salesChannelContext->getContext();
        $buy_order = $transaction->getOrder()->getOrderNumber();
        $session_id = $_COOKIE["session-"];
        $amount = $transaction->getOrderTransaction()->getAmount()->getTotalPrice();
        $return_url = $transaction->getReturnUrl(); // Too long, max 256

        $return_url_fake = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/gentawebpay/finish?order=" . $buy_order;

        $redirectUrl = $this->sendReturnUrlToExternalGateway($return_url_fake, $buy_order, $session_id, $amount);

        $this->gentaPaymentTransactionRepository->create([
            [
                'order_number' => $buy_order,
                'transaction_token' => $redirectUrl->getToken(),
                'sw_return_url' => $return_url,
            ]
        ], $context);

        // Redirect to external gateway
        return new RedirectResponse( $redirectUrl->getUrl().'?token_ws='.$redirectUrl->getToken() );
    }

Finalize method:
public function finalize(AsyncPaymentTransactionStruct $transaction, Request $request, SalesChannelContext $salesChannelContext): void
    {

        $token_ws = $request->get('token_ws') ?? null;

        $transactionId = $transaction->getOrderTransaction()->getId();

        if (!$token_ws) {
            die ('not a normal flow.');  
        }

        $response = (new Transaction)->commit($token_ws);
        $context = $salesChannelContext->getContext();

        if ($response->isApproved()) {

            $this->transactionStateHandler->paid($transaction->getOrderTransaction()->getId(), $context);

        } else {
            $this->transactionStateHandler->fail($transaction->getOrderTransaction()->getId(), $context);
            
            throw PaymentException::asyncFinalizeInterrupted(
                $transaction->getOrderTransaction()->getId(),
                'An error occurred during the communication with external payment gateway'
            );
            
        }
    }

Send return url to external gateway method:
private function sendReturnUrlToExternalGateway(string $getReturnUrl, string $buy_order, string $session_id, float $amount): object
    {
        $paymentProviderUrl = '';

        // Do some API Call to your payment provider
        $transaction = new Transaction();
        $response = $transaction->create($buy_order, $session_id, $amount, $getReturnUrl);

        $paymentProviderUrl = $response;

        return $paymentProviderUrl;
    }

The error I am getting:

Not sure if it's a Shopware issue or from the payment provider. Any idea would be appreciated

Did you find any solution to this?

@RohitKundale not yet, I had to leave standing by because I couldn't find any info about it and I am not that expert on Shopware honestly.
